# What is the object of 'the relaying of?

Tags: usage

I think it's just ***a letter***, which means ***the relaying of a letter*** and ***the communication that a certain employment exists*** are in a parallel structure, but it's a little bit ambiguous.

> Other late twentieth century, researchers sought to measure how fast
> and how far news, rumours or innovations moved. More recent research
> has shown that even emotional states can be transmitted through a
> network. Thought distinguishing between endogenous and exogenous
> network effects is far from easy, the evidence of this kind of
> contagion is clear: ‘Students with studious roommates become more
> studious. Diners sitting next to heavy eaters eat more food.’ However,
> according to Christakis and Fowler, we cannot transmit ideas and
> behaviours much beyond our friends’ friends’ friends (in other words,
> across just three degrees of separation). This is because the
> transmission and reception of an idea or behaviour requires a stronger connection than ***the
> relaying of a letter(in the case of Milgram's
> experiment) or the communication that a certain employment
> opportunity exists***. Merely knowing people is not the same as being
> able to influence them to study more or over-eat. Imitation is indeed
> the sincerest form of flattery, even when it is unconscious.

[The Square and the Tower: Networks and Power, from the Freemasons to Facebook](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=QIYqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=This%20is%20because%20the%20transmission%20and%20reception%20of%20an%20idea%20or%20behaviour%20requires%20a%20stronger%20connection%20than%20the%20relaying%20of%20a%20letter%20or%20the%20communication%20that%20a%20certain%20employment%20opportunity%20exists.&source=bl&ots=0OKNVWVokA&sig=ACfU3U03Q0ewY89BHR6eBRl5D4V-Z_wJ7Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj66sSq-tD1AhXHdd4KHaAlB-wQ6AF6BQiVAhAD#v=onepage&q=This%20is%20because%20the%20transmission%20and%20reception%20of%20an%20idea%20or%20behaviour%20requires%20a%20stronger%20connection%20than%20the%20relaying%20of%20a%20letter%20or%20the%20communication%20that%20a%20certain%20employment%20opportunity%20exists.&f=false)

Comment: I think that your analysis is spot on. Why do you think that the sentence is ambiguous?

Comment: One of the definitions of communication is 'a letter or message containing information or news,' which makes it ambiguous at least to me.

Comment: Presumably "Milgram's experiment" involved an actual letter, while "the communication of an employment opportunity" could well be through an advertisement in a newspaper or some other means.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, the meaning of "letter" is ambiguous. You could say something like "letter of the alphabet" or "epistle" to distinguish between the different meanings.